# How can I achieve a smooth animation in Adobe Premiere?

Tags: premiere, animation

I want to make a video in Adobe Premiere, I noticed that there is a certain kind of animation that video editors use in video essays, here is an example:
[Check Your Schadenfreude](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tva0xq-eDvI)
You can see how there is a smooth animated motion that appears when a text is highlighted or an object is being revealed, how can I make a similar effect? I was able to make something that is a bit close to it but I can't make it perfect, are there any presets for this? what should I search for?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add ease-in to the motion. That's where the motion slows as it approaches the final position. You can add it quickly by hitting the <kbd>f9</kbd> key. This sets the speed of the keyframe to zero, and gives it 16% influence. To change the effect you cn edit this by opening the keyframe properties dialogue. Hit <kbd>ctrl/⌘</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>k</kbd>. Alternatively open the graph editor and click on the position property to show the graph. You can adjust the speed of the keyframe and its influence by dragging the Bézier handles there.

You might want to [duckduckgo the 12 principles of animation](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=12%20principles%20of%20animation&t=ffab&atb=v53-6&ia=web), if you want to do some extra reading. This is a valuable guide to creating pleasing motion in animation and motion graphics, that is as true now as it was when it was written back in the days of cels and paint.